# Javascript Regex matching logical or

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if JavaScript includes the logical or when pattern matching. I would like to check if the user is either using @hotmail.com or @gmail.com, with anything allowed to come before it, and nothing allowed after the @hotmail or @gmail.com.
Instead of having to write two separate conditions to check each one is there away to combine it into one test. Thank you.

Comment: "alternation" has been a basic feature of regular expression syntax since it was devised decades ago. [Read up on the `|` operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^(.+)@(hotmail|gmail)\.com$/
```

Comment: What does the ^(.) do. I know that, ^ means match the front character, but what is (.*) doing. Sorry for such a basic question, I am not proficient in regex

Comment: Just to mention that I've replaced the * by +,
the . means any character
the .* means zero or more of any character. 
the .+ means 1 or more of any character